# Adventure Works SQL Server Enquiry

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am writing a SQL query using the AdventureWorks 2014 database.

I want to show Which orders contain more than two products? Show order number, order value, and number of products that the order contains.

I tried to write statement by itself (see below), but I'd like to be able to  solve the relation :

```
select SalesOrderID , ProductID , LineTotal
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
order by SalesOrderID
```

[image]

Comment: Is this some homework you have to do? Try doing some research on COUNT(), HAVING and JOIN.

Comment: George your last 3 question are all the same homework. Do your own homework so you learn something. If want some examples check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: I know that you can't ask about what you don't know but the magical word you are looking for is : [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql). From that point you just to to filter on row that [have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) more than 2

Comment: And read the lesson 1rst!

Comment: Why tag with mysql and adventureworks and sql server? Guessing this has nothing to do with mysql as the screenshot is clearly sql server.

Comment: @NinaSatragno  , Juan Carlos Oropeza     :  iam trying to learn sql server with big database so the person who not asking will never learn one day

Comment: @GeorgeKouki Your arent asking for tips. You are asking for us to do your job. Last question you didnt wait 1h before asking here again. Go read a tutorial, Watch some videos in youTube.

Comment: Also take the query you have and TRY doing some functions. Get syntax errors, learn by doing.

Comment: The proof is both question before use `group by` this one also need it and you still dont know it. So go back read `group by` examples so you understand it and learn it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza , i did it after 7 hours , can you check my answer !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SalesOrderID,
       COUNT(ProductID) as total_products,
       SUM(LineTotal) as total_invoice
FROM SalesOrderDetail s
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) > 2
ORDER BY s.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: thank you , am trying now and I did yesterday many examples by my hand am not lazy ...

Answer (score 0):

@Juan Carlos Oropeza

i did it can you check if there is something wrong with it

```
select  s.SalesOrderID,
        a.SalesOrderCount, 
        a.ProductCount,
        sum(LineTotal) as OrderValue 
from  Sales.SalesOrderDetail s , 
      (select SalesOrderID ,
              count(SalesOrderID)  as SalesOrderCount ,
              count(productid) as ProductCount
       from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
       group by SalesOrderID 
      ) a
where s.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID
group by a.salesordercount, s.SalesOrderID, a.ProductCount
having a.ProductCount >2 
order by s.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Im glad this time you try. Check my answer. That give you the two value you ask in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    SalesOrderID, 
    sum(LineTotal) as [order value], 
    count(SalesOrderID) as [number of Product] 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
    group by SalesOrderID having count(SalesOrderID)>=2 
    order by SalesOrderID desc
```

Comment: In the future, please format your answer and provide some degree of explanation that might help the OP to better understand your proposed solution.

Answer (score -1):

This code would give your expected answer

```
SELECT SalesOrderID 
        ,ProductID
        ,LineTotal
        ,'Sales Order ' +CAST(SalesOrderID AS VARCHAR(100))+'  Contains Productid of'+CAST(ProductID  AS VARCHAR(100))
        AS [ProductsCountPerOrder] 
       ,Productscount
    FROM
(
SELECT   salesorderid , 
         productid , 
         linetotal , 
         Count(productid)OVER(partition BY salesorderid ORDER BY salesorderid) AS productscount 
FROM     sales.salesorderdetail 
)dt 
WHERE dt.productscount>2 
ORDER BY salesorderid
```

Comment: Dont promote laziness

Comment: ohh! i thought he is new to sql

Comment: He is, but if you check his other question are all the same. He didnt try to read what group by is.

Comment: sorry bro i didn't see his previous Questions

Comment: btw, you dont need a subquery. Just `GROUP BY + HAVING`. Also you wont get the correct result becasue you get a `COUNT()` for each item on the `salesorder`